# The visibility of variable which write after volatile variable write

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, volatile

```java
public class Test {
    private static volatile boolean flag = false;
    private static int i = 1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            flag = true;
            i += 1;
        }).start();
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (!flag) {
                if (i != 1) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(flag);
            System.out.println(i);
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Variable `i` is written after volatile variable flag, but the code output true 2. It seems the modify of `i` by the first thread is visible to the second thread.

According to my understanding, variable I should be written before flag, then the second thread can be aware of the change.

Answer (score 2):

Accordingly to the language standard (§17.4):

> A field may be declared volatile, in which case the Java Memory Model
> ensures that all threads see a consistent value for the variable

So informally, all threads will have a view of the must update value of that variable.

However, the *volatile* clause not only implies ensure *visibility guarantee* of the target variable but also [full volatile visibility guarantee](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html), namely:

> Actually, the visibility guarantee of Java volatile goes beyond the
> volatile variable itself. The visibility guarantee is as follows:
>
> If Thread A writes to a volatile variable and Thread B subsequently
> reads the same volatile variable, **then all variables visible to Thread
> A before writing the volatile variable, will also be visible to Thread
> B after it has read the volatile variable.**

> If Thread A reads a
> volatile variable, then all all variables visible to Thread A when
> reading the volatile variable will also be re-read from main memory.
>
> According to my understanding, variable I should be written before
> flag, then the second thread can be aware of the change.

*"All variables visible to the Thread A before writing the volatile variable"*, it does not refer to **operation** over those variables.

Comment: What is the definition of a "variable visible to the thread A"?

Comment: @Yar refers to any variable that Thread A has accessed or modified before writing to the volatile variable.

Comment: All variables visible to the Thread A before writing the volatile variable", it does not refer to operation over those variables.

What do you mean by this ? @dreamcrash

Answer (score 2):

Your code suffers from a data-race.

A data race is when there are 2 memory actions to the same address which are not ordered by a happens before relation, and at least one of these actions is a write.

In this case the write to `i` is the problem.

The write to `i`, is after the write to the volatile variable `flag` and hence there is no happens before relation between writing the `i` and reading `i`.

If you would write `i` before you write to the `flag`, there would be the following happens before relation:

1. write of `i` happens before write of `flag` due to the program order rule
2. write of `flag` happens before read of `flag` due to volatile variable rule  (on the hardware level this is a task for cache coherence).
3. the read of `flag` happens before the read of `i` due to program order rule.

Because the happens before relation is transitive, the write of `i` happens before the read if `i`.

So like you already indicated, if you move the write of `i` in front of the write of the flag; the data race is gone.

Answer (score 1):

The memory model defines guarantees, however anything may happen on top of them.

On x86, all writes have release semantics, and as soon as you write to a variable, its updated value will be visible as soon as possible from other threads.

So the fact that actions before writing to a volatile variable happen-before actions after reading to it, does not prevent actions after writing to it to become visible after reading it.